# How to search human names in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to search human name from the dataframe. I have a very large dataset where i need to tokenize everyword but human names should be full names. I am just creating this as an example.

```
Date                             Text
09.05.2019                       His name is Detlef Schubert. 
04.09.2019                       Mr. Klau Gerd is a good person.
```

So i want the output like this:

```
Date                             Text
09.05.2019                       His
09.05.2019                       name
09.05.2019                       is
09.05.2019                       Detlef Schubert
04.09.2019                       Mr. Klaus Gerd
04.09.2019                       is
04.09.2019                       a
04.09.2019                       good 
04.09.2019                       person.
```

So far i am doing this:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')['Text'].str.split().explode()
```

But i want full name when i do tokenizing

Comment: Wouldn't this need an NLP library like `nltk` perhaps? Pretty sure it's near impossible to do that with just `pandas`. There's no way to detect what are proper names without some sort of corpa.

Comment: How would pandas know what a "full human name" is?

Comment: if the names are _always_ in proper case you could use a regex to extract words that are in proper case for more than 1 + occurances.

Comment: You are right. I edited my question tags. It must require nltk but i am new in this.

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What is a "human name"?